# Rewrite $\sec^2 (x) \cdot \sin^2 (x) $in terms of $\cos (x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Write $\sec^2 (x) \cdot \sin^2 (x)$ in terms of $\cos (x)$.

I was not able to answer this question on a pre-calculus exam and my professor will not explain to me how to answer it; I wish to learn.

Here is what I did on the test:

$\sec^2 (x) \cdot \sin^2 (x)$ = $\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{\cos^2 (x)}} \cdot \  \sqrt{1-\cos^2 (x)} = \frac{1}{\cos (x)} \cdot  \frac{\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2}}{1} = \frac{\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2}}{\cos (x)}$

What did I do wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @WesleyStrik You seem to have lost a minus sign in the last step of your comment.

Comment: I got lost on the last step. Is there a name for this kind of problem? Maybe I can watch another example and try to apply the concept to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The trick is literally to first express both of these in terms of cosines and then to simply take the product.

Comment: I cannot answer your question because some guy closed your question.

Comment: What you did wrong was that you calculated:
$$ \sec(x) \cdot \sin(x)$$
In terms of $\cos(x)$, which would have been fine if that were the question. You should however take the square of every expression, because that's what is being asked.

Comment: oh I see! you combined the fraction then separated the fraction because of the same denominator. Thank you @WesleyStrik

Comment: Because it says that I should put it in terms of cos(x), is it okay then that it is still squared? Do I have to square root?

Comment: Yes or I use distributivity $a(b+c)= ab +ac$

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is a function in terms of $x$, right?

Comment: I added an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

$\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x} \\ \sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2x$

Put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that we have that: 
$$\sec^2  x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}  $$ $$ \sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2x$$

So if we multiply the two and use distributivity:
$$(\sec^2  x) \cdot(\sin^2x )=(\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}) \cdot(1 - \cos^2x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x} -\frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x}= \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} -1$$

Notice now that we expressed this in terms of $\cos(x)$, we now have a function in terms of $\cos(x)$, namely:
$$ f(\cos x )=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x} -1$$
Or if we let $z=\cos(x)$
$$ f(z )=\frac{1}{z^2} -1$$
would you not say that this is expressed in terms of $z$ $(=\cos(x))$?

Comment: $z^2$ in the denominator in the last step.

Answer (score 0):

$sec^2(x)\bullet sin^2(x)={1\over{cos^2(x)}}\left(1-cos^2(x)\right)={1\over{cos^2(x)}}-1$